# Setting Charset for String

Tags: java

I use forbiddenapis to check my code. It gives an error:

```
[forbiddenapis] Forbidden class/interface use: java.lang.String#<init>(byte[]) 
[forbiddenapis]   in org.a.b.MyObject (MyObject.java:14)
```

Which points to:

```
String finalString = new String(((ByteArrayOutputStream) out).toByteArray());
```

How can I resolve it? I know that I can set a Charset, i.e.:

```
Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(myString);
```

However since there is used byte, which charset should I use to avoid a problem with different characters?

Comment: `new String(byteArray, charSet)`.

Comment: The charset you use should be the charset in which the bytes are encoded - do you know that up front?

Comment: If you're using UTF-8, consider `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`.

Comment: There is no `Charset` that can decode every byte sequence emitted by every other encoder. You have to have some metadata to indicate the encoding of the byte array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `FileReader`. This is an old utility class to read files in the default platform encoding. That is not suited for portable files. The code is unportable.

`String / Reader / Writer` holds Unicode. When converting from `byte[] / InputStream / OutputStream` one needs to indicate the encoding of those bytes, binary data.

```
String s = new String(bytes, charset);
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes(charset);
```

It seems that the message mentions FileReader and complains about its

```
new String(bytes);
```

which uses the default encoding, as would:

```
string.getBytes();
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need insight into the charset with which the bytes were encoded in the first place. If you're confident it'd always be UTF8, you could just use the `String` constructor:

```
new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```