# Using non-default charset for FileWriter

Tags: java

I'm checking my code with forbiddenapis and it gives error:

```
[forbiddenapis] Forbidden class/interface use: java.io.FileWriter [Uses default charset]
[forbiddenapis]   in org.a.b.FileObject (FileObject.java:45)
```

which points to first line of:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
try {
  BufferedWriter x = new BufferedWriter(fw);
  try {
    x.write(Integer.toString(value));
  }
  finally {
    x.close();
  }
}
finally {
  fw.close();
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: As @JoopEggen said in [his answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38859744/3788176), "Do not use FileReader. This is an old utility class to read files in the default platform encoding. That is not suited for portable files. The code is unportable.". Infer from this that `FileWriter` suffers the same issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't with FileWriter. Use a `FileOutputStream` and an `OutputStreamWriter`.

```
 try(OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("File");
     Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "CHARSET")){
   // ...

 }
```

An alternative would be:

```
try(Writer writer=Files.newBufferedWriter(Path, Charset.forName("charset"))){
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Read the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html):

> The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding and the default byte-buffer size are acceptable. To specify these values yourself, construct an OutputStreamWriter on a FileOutputStream.